# Active Admin file app/admin/**.rb load take a lot of time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, activeadmin

My Rails Project have 30 active admin file in app/admin/ .

When I change some code and reload, Opening page take 6 second.
Then I delete all file in app/admin/**.rb . Opening page take just 1 second.
This phenomenon happens everywhere directory.

So I want to load app/admin file only in localhost:3000/admin directory.

or find good solution to shorten page reload speed.

thanks.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Lots of discussion around this: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/697 and https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/4558 are most recent.